# ! LaTeX Error: Command \tocchapter undefined - no solution found

Tags: mactex, markdown, tinytex

I am trying to convert on a Mac (IOS 11.5.2.) in R Markdown a code to a pdf file but since I enteder a code junk (importing a csv. file and producing a table) I get following error msg:

I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Masterthesis.log.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \tocchapter undefined.
```

Previously I had problems with .sty files environ and threeparttable but installed them manually in my markdown wd and my TinyTex subfolder "TeXLive".

Urgent help is much appreciated

I can post the .log file error but I will quote the last part of it:

```
) (./threeparttable.sty
Package: threeparttable 2003/06/13  v 3.0
\@tempboxb=\box68
)
(/Users/Simon/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttablex/threeparttab
lex.sty
Package: threeparttablex 2013/07/23 v0.3 by daleif
(./environ.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \tocchapter undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.30 \renewcommand{\tocchapter}
                               [3]{% 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11082 strings out of 480559
 157029 string characters out of 5902619
 464687 words of memory out of 5000000
 28563 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 406420 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,0n,66p,331b,270s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: why is threeparttablex coming from a standard location but threeparttable.sty coming from the current directory? are you sure you have compatible versions? (although you appear to have latest versions of each)

Comment: your `environ.sty` appears to be the wrong file, `environ.sty` prints version information to the log which you are not showing and does not define \tocchapter

Comment: I had problems with both threeparttable.sty not found and environ.sty not found and downloaded them manually while not being sure to which repository to add them. Not detecting said files was my initial problem which I hoped that I'd solved.

Comment: but the file with name environ.sty in your local directory is not environ.sty according to the log you show

Comment: doesn't tinytex give you access to `tlmgr` so you can install poackages via `tlmgr install environ` ?

Comment: Ok I removed all the packages and files I downloaded manually and now, when knitting the markdown doc, tlmgr automatically downloaded all the missing packages. I had to try like 4 times until all where installed as it apparently only loads 1 package per run.
Anyway, it works!! Thanks !

Comment: glad you got it working, I'm not sure it has any generally applicable answer so you could delete? Or you could post the above comment as a self answer and accept it?